# Cursor style doesn't stay updated

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse-cursor

I have a normal Windows GUI application (made using the API, not MFC) and as I move my mouse on and off the application and the mouse changes styles (like when you move it over the border, it changes to a resize arrow, etc.) but sometimes it "sticks" in that style, so that I can move the mouse around and it will stay in a resize arrow or whatever, even after it's off the window border. It fixes itself if I move it over another control.

It's just an inconvenience, but it looks unprofessional and I would like to fix it. How can I make it where it stays up to date all the time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set a valid cursor handle when you register your window class. See `WNDCLASSEX::hCursor`. Use `LoadCursor` to load a valid cursor. Like,

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
...
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
...
RegisterClassEx(&wc);
```

Answer (score 9):

tenfour's answer is correct.  Here's a little more background.

When the mouse moves within a window, and it's not captured, the window will get a `WM_SETCURSOR` message.  The message name can be a little confusing.  It's basically the window's opportunity to set the cursor, not an instruction to set the cursor.

A window can handle this message by calling `SetCursor` and returning.

A window can also punt by passing the message to `DefWindowProc` to get the default behavior.  The default behavior is to look at the `hCursor` field in the `WNDCLASS` for the window.  This is why tenfour's answer works.

(It's actually a bit more complicated than that, since the `DefWindowProc` first gives the parent window a chance to intervene.)

If you want to do something dynamic, like choose a cursor depending on some state variable, then you should have to handle the `WM_SETCURSOR` so that it calls `SetCursor` with whatever cursor is appropriate and then returns `TRUE`.

See [`SetCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.